# Is there a way to get the file path for a loaded module in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible, given a loaded module, to get its file path?

```
const MyModule = require('./MyModule');
const MyOtherModule = require('../otherfolder/MyOtherModule');

function print(){
   console.log(thisIsThePathTo(MyModule));  <--- Should print the absolute path of the loaded module
   console.log(thisIsThePathTo(MyOtherModule));  <--- Should print the absolute path of the loaded module
}
```

I saw require.resolve but I need the opposite lookup...
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`require.main`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_main) describes the `module` object.

The module has an `id` and a `path`, however those are not exported. You can add those properties to the `module.exports` object to export them. Then, in a separate module, you can access them via `MyOtherModule.id` or `MyOtherModule.path`

For example,

In `MyOtherModule/index.js`:

```js
myOtherModuleFunction = function() {
    console.log('This is module 2')
}

module.exports = {
    // spread all properties in module.exports
    ...module,
    // then add the exports
    exports: myOtherModuleFunction 
}
```

and in `MyModule/MyModule.js`,

```js
module.exports = {
    ...module,
    exports: { someFunction: () => console.log('MyModule') }
}
```

and in `MyModule/index.js`:

```js
const MyModule = require('./MyModule');
const MyOtherModule = require('../../MyOtherModule/');

function thisIsThePathTo(module) {
    return module.path
}

function print(){
    console.log(thisIsThePathTo(MyModule))
    console.log(thisIsThePathTo(MyOtherModule))
 }

print()
```

Running `node src/MyModule/index.js` outputs:

```
/.../stackoverflow/62043302/src/MyModule/
/.../stackoverflow/62043302/src/MyOtherModule
```

And if you print `module.id` instead of `module.path`, you'll get:

```
/.../stackoverflow/62043302/src/MyModule/index.js
/.../stackoverflow/62043302/src/MyOtherModule/index.js
```

However, spreading all properties includes `module.children` and `module.parent`, and you'll also have to use `module.exports` when accessing the so you probably only want to include `id` or `path`, like so:

````js
myOtherModuleFunction = function() {
    console.log('This is module 2')
}

const { id, path } = module

module.exports = {
    id,
    path,
    myOtherModuleFunction,
}```

and require like so:

```js
const {id: otherModuleId, myOtherModuleFunction } = require('MyOtherModule')
````

This can get messy. If you're importing modules you did not author, you will not have the option to lookup the `id` or `path` (unless the authors added it to `module.exports`).

Comment: Nice :) although I was hoping for something that doesn't require changing the original component

Comment: @Udi yeah, unfortunately I'm not sure how that's possible. Perhaps with webpack there's a way to repackage each component?